# KDE Plasma: Maximized window on second monitor leaves large gap

Tags: kde, window, maximized

As can be seen in the following screenshot, I have a dual monitor setup in KDE Plasma 5.12.9, where I have a panel at the bottom of my left screen, but not at the bottom of my right screen.

**Screenshot of desktop**

[image: Screenshot of desktop]

Nevertheless, when I maximize windows on my right screen it leaves a gap for the panel that is actually located on the left screen, which I do not want. Is there a way to disable this behaviour and get truly maximized windows on the right screen without making maximized windows on the left screen go above or behind the panel (and without auto-hiding the panel)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by changing and re-changing the display alignments in the display settings.

[image: display-settings]

So, it was lined up, I moved it around, pressed apply, then moved it back to original position, pressed apply. It's the same settings I started with, but it got rid of that gap.

I should note that this was on a different version than yours (5.16.9, Fedora 31).

Comment: Nice, that did the trick - the gap is gone...

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me too, on Kubuntu 19.04 and Plasma 5.16.5.

Comment: Also worked for me on KDE Neon (20.04) and Plasma 5.19.4.

Comment: Worked if I put them on top of each other temporarily, not if I swapped left-right.

Comment: I have discovered the more exact problem! If no primary display is selected (or maybe also in other cases), the Display arrangement pane only lets you make the offset (1919,0) via snapping. This means there is a single pixel column of overlap between the two displays, causing the panel on one screen to affect the other. If I enable a primary monitor or temporarily make the screens overlap and then move them back then the snapping gives an offset of (1920,0), which results in no overlap, hence no maximisation problems. They should really fix this bug.